# Send multiply files with asyncio server

Tags: python, asynchronous, server, file-transfer

Here is server.py

```python
import asyncio
import aiofile

async def handler(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(n=-1)
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print('Addr', addr)
    # photo_120721_215652.jpg
    name = data[:23].decode()
    async with aiofile.async_open(name, 'wb') as afp:
        await afp.write(data[23:])
    print("handler end")


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handler, '0.0.0.0', 8888)
    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is client.py

```python
async def send_photos_to_server(filelist):
    retry = 0
    for file in filelist:
        while True:
            try:
                reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('192.168.1.100', 8888)
            except OSError:
                while retry != 5:
                    await asyncio.sleep(3)
                    retry += 1
            else:
                break # exit the loop 
        if retry == 5:
            print("No connection after {} retries")
            break

        name = file.split('/')[-1].encode()
        writer.write(name)
        await writer.drain()

        async with aiofile.async_open(file, 'rb') as afp:
            afp_reader = await afp.read(length=-1)
        writer.write(afp_reader)
        await writer.drain()
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()

filelist = ['./photos/photo_120721_215652.jpg',
            './photos/photo_120721_215654.jpg',
            './photos/photo_120721_215656.jpg']

asyncio.run(send_photos_to_server(filelist))
```

So this code is working. But I'm not sure that it's a proper way to do that. Every time to send a new file, we create a new connection. Sure, I could pack all three files into an archive, but I'm not sure it is handy. Also, it's inconvenient to put filename to sending a message because then on the server-side, I have to, somehow, find it. So can someone explain how to modify this code for better practice? I've just started to learn async io and not good at it.

Comment: what did you try? Did you try to open connection before `for`-loop, and close it after `for`-loop? But I think it would need big changes in `handler` - it was created only to send one file. And it would need some loop to send many files. Other problem can be to send names - it may get all names as single string. It may need also info after last filename that it was last name. So it may be more complex and using compression `zip` may be much simpler.

Comment: You could send all names as one string with separator ie. `;` and handler should use `split(';')` to get list of names. If it get list with more then one name then it should use compress all files in one zip file. OR it should sends data with some header which will have information how load is every image and send all images as one data. So you would have to create own `protocol` (rules which describe how client and server should communicate - like in protocols `HTTP`, `FTP`, `SMTP`)

Comment: sending filename before data in normal - every protocol sends some extra informations (headers) before data. For example HTTP first sends headers, next empty line and next data (body) and other side can read headers byte after byte until it get empty line (two ENTERS - `'\n\n'`) and one of the header has information how many bytes has body - so it it will know how many bytes of data (body) it has to read.

Comment: "what did you try? Did you try to open connection before for-loop, and close it after for-loop? But I think it would need big changes in handler - it was created only to send one file" - you talking about server and it's fine. Its designed to do `handler` function after recieving connection, after that it is save it to file. My question was more about client side and it's way of working. I got what you propose about filename.

Comment: you can't change only client - you will have to change also server. If client will use one connection and for-loop to send many files then server will have to also use `for`-loop to get all files.

Answer (score 2):

Servers use `protocols` - it meas rules which describe what one side has to send and how to read it on another size.

For example `HTTP` first sends headers, next empty line, and next data (body). One of the header has information how long is body.

Other side first has to read data `byte after byte` until it find empty line (`'n\n'`) and then it has headers and it can find how long is body, and read correct number of bytes.

---

The same way you can create own protocol.

I assumed you want to send all files in one connection.

You can send number of files + `\n`, and next uses `for`-loop to send filename + `\n`, file size + `\n`, file data.

And other side should do similar - first read all to `\n` to get number of files, and use `for`-loop to again read all to `\n` to get filename, read all to `\n` to get size, use `size` to read file data.

---

And it shows that it may be simpler to compress data with zip and send it - and other side will have all information - filename, size, data - inside this zip file.

Of course you can reduce it and still send every file in separated connection.

---

Example code

**server.py**

```
import asyncio
import aiofile

async def handler(reader, writer):

    # --- before for-loop ---
    
    data = await reader.read(n=-1)
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print('Addr', addr)

    # get number of images + `\n`
    start = 0
    end = data.find(b'\n', start)
    item = data[start:end]
    print('[DEBUG] start,end:', start, end, item)
    number = int(item.decode())
    print('number:', number)
    
    print('--------')

    # --- for-loop ---

    for _ in range(number):
        # get filename + '\n' 
        start = end+1
        end = data.find(b'\n', start)
        item = data[start:end]
        print('[DEBUG] start,end:', start, end, item)
        name = item.decode()
        print('name:', name)

        # get size + '\n'
        start = end+1
        end = data.find(b'\n', start)
        item = data[start:end]
        print('[DEBUG] start,end:', start, end, item)
        size = int(item.decode())
        print('size:', size)
        
        # get data
        start = end+1
        end = start+size-1
        item = data[start:end]
        print('[DEBUG] start,end:', start, end, item[:10])
        async with aiofile.async_open(name, 'wb') as afp:
            await afp.write(item)
            
        print('--------')

    # --- after for-loop ---
        
    print("handler end")


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handler, '0.0.0.0', 8888)
    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

**client.py**

```
import asyncio
import aiofile

async def send_photos_to_server(filelist):

    # --- before for-loop ---
    
    retry = 0

    while True:
        try:
            reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('0.0.0.0', 8888)
        except OSError:
            while retry != 5:
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
                retry += 1
        else:
            break # exit the loop 
    if retry == 5:
        print("No connection after {} retries")
        return
    
    # send number of images + '\n'
    text = str(len(filelist)) + '\n'
    writer.write(text.encode())
    await writer.drain()
    
    # --- for-loop ---
    
    for filename in filelist:

        # send filename + '\n'
        name = filename.split('/')[-1]
        text = name + '\n'
        writer.write(text.encode())
        await writer.drain()

        async with aiofile.async_open(filename, 'rb') as afp:
            afp_reader = await afp.read(length=-1)

        # send size + '\n'
        size = str(len(afp_reader)) 
        text = size + '\n'
        writer.write(text.encode())
        await writer.drain()

        # send data
        writer.write(afp_reader)
        await writer.drain()
        
        
    # --- after for-loop ---
    
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

filelist = [
    '/home/furas/test/image1.png',
    '/home/furas/test/image2.png',
    '/home/furas/test/image3.png',
]

asyncio.run(send_photos_to_server(filelist))
```